# Create installer for java web application (linux and Windows)

Tags: installation, multiplatform

How to create installer for web application to run on both Windows and Linux? I need no more than extact some jar, jsp and xml files into a chosen directory. (Web server and database should be already installed, when our app is installed)
There can be two output files - one for Windows, one for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://izpack.org/ is a fully-fledged cross-platform java installer-generator, and it's awesome.

But I'm not sure you need that exactly ..

I think, maybe, you just want a .war file? (i.e. a web application archive)

Here's an old article about war files:

http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WCC3.html

Answer (score 0):

Our product, [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) is a multiplatform installer that can do what you want. It is commercial but we have discounts for small companies and free licenses for open source projects. For example of web applications packaged with BitRock, check [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org)